# Django - query all records matching current logged in user

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm struggling to understand how to format queries in views - especially in regards to the current logged in user. I would like to display all books whose user_added value matches the current logged in user's ID.

**models.py**

```
class books(models.Model):
        user_added = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*i'm using Django's Users model and functionality*

**forms.py**

```
class books_list(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = books
        fields = ['user_added', 'title']
```

**views.py**

```
class booksListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # id = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `user_added` with `self.request.user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class booksListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return books.objects.filter(user_added=self.request.user)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thank you for the response, i'm getting a '__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' response (I believe due to having both 'LoginRquiredMixin' and 'Listview' but I'm not sure what mistake i've made)

Comment: @GameAnalysis: did you use `.as_view()` in the `urls`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf

Comment: of course, because it's a class based view, no I hadn't, thank you for the help